# odd re.match behavior Python vs regex101/python

Tags: python, regex

I ran into this weird behavior, which works fine in regex101.com with Python setting, but fails to capture in actual python3.7:

```
import re
match_str = r'(?P<header>.*?)(FROG)'
pattern_comment = re.compile( match_str )

# this sort of works
txt = 'this is a FROG'
matches = pattern_comment.match(txt, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches) # <re.Match object; span=(8, 14), match='a FROG'>
print(matches['header']) . # 'a '

# this fails to capture in python, but works in regex101
txt = 'this FROG'
matches = pattern_comment.match(txt, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

It is not clear to me, why in first example the `header` captured is `a` and not `this is a`, and why it fails to capture in the second example. Same behavior is seen while using `search` instead of `match`.

Any ideas how to capture it fully like in regex101?

Comment: Move `re.MULTILINE` to the `compile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a flag as the start position. Flags can only be added when the regex is compiled:

```
import re
match_str = r'(?P<header>.*?)(FROG)'
pattern_comment = re.compile(match_str, re.MULTILINE)

txt = 'this is a FROG'
matches = pattern_comment.match(txt)
print(matches)
print(matches['header'])

txt = 'this FROG'
matches = pattern_comment.match(txt)
print(matches)
```

The second argument to [`Pattern.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) and [`Pattern.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) is `pos`. You were passing [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) which is 8. That means the matching was starting at the 8th character.

Comment: that helps. Still if I change to `'this \nis a FROG'` the first line is not captured

Comment: @DimaLituiev `.` doesn't match `\n` - use `[\s\S]` or add the option `re.DOTALL`

Comment: @DimaLituiev That's because you're using `re.match` without `re.DOTALL`